# How do I get Babel to output a file's AST?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Is there a way I can get Babel to output the AST of a file, as a JSON or similar, rather than condense it back into JS?

The reason is that I want to be able to do some simple static analysis / code gen, and while I aim to eventually do it within a plugin for Babel (or similar), I feel it would simplify things significantly if I can start with a static model.

Comment: Do you just want to parse the code or do you want to apply Babel's transformations? There are quite a few JS parsers out there. Babel uses its own fork of acorn, called babylon. Have a look at http://astexplorer.net/, which features popular parsers (note: I maintain that site). It actually also allows you to prototype Babel plugins (but not for Babel v6 yet).

Comment: Specifically I want to be able to run Babel's *parser* plugins, so the output can contain (for example) flow annotation data. I want the output before it's transformed into a plain-ES3/5 tree though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [babylon](https://github.com/babel/babylon), babel's own parser:

`npm install -g babylon`

`babylon your_file.js > ast.json`

---

Node API example and source:
https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babylon

Also the [babel plugin handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-plugin-handbook) might come in handy for AST reference, and to get started with plugin development.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I've been looking for!

Comment: Seems like babylon is now @babel/parser https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-parser

Answer (score 3):

you should check out [ast-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ast-source) - it can take `babel` as a parser when it builds the tree.

Example from their npmjs page:

```
import ASTSource from "ast-source"
import estraverse from "estraverse"
import fs from "fs"

function transform(AST) {
    var replaced = {
        "type": "babel",
        "value": 42,
        "raw": "42"
    };
    return estraverse.replace(AST, {
        enter: function (node) {
            if (node.type === estraverse.Syntax.Literal) {
                return replaced;
            }
        }
    });
}

var source = new ASTSource(fs.readFileSync("./input.js", "utf-8"), {
    filePath: "./input.js"
});
var output = source.transform(transform).output();
console.log(output.code);// => "var a = 42;" 
console.dir(output.map.toString()); // => source map 
fs.writeFileSync("./output.js", output.codeWithMap, "utf-8");
```